# okhttp :path header HPACK implementation

Tags: okhttp, http2

Just trying to make an HTTP/2 POST request and wondering if OkHttp implements HPACK when sending the header :path, does anyone know?

Answer (score 1):

Does not look like it does from a [quick search of the code](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/6903b89e0b760aba4f89737f717d4503b1889e1e/okhttp/src/main/java/okhttp3/internal/http2/Hpack.kt):

```
      name.startsWith(Header.PSEUDO_PREFIX) && TARGET_AUTHORITY != name -> {
        // Follow Chromes lead - only include the :authority pseudo header, but exclude all other
        // pseudo headers. Literal Header Field without Indexing - Indexed Name.
        writeInt(headerNameIndex, PREFIX_4_BITS, 0)
        writeByteString(value)
      }
```

This makes sense as for many HTTP uses (e.g. browsers) the path will change frequently so no point indexing the value for later reuse.